# What does もう mean in this sentence?

Tags: usage, adverbs

彼はもう英語を教えるまい。 (Most probably, he won't teach English any more.) I got this sentence from [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/487/does-ou-you-mashou-conjugation-have-a-negative-form/1482#comment13314_1482). もう doesn't seem necessary to use or have. Isn't the meaning the same if it was like this: 彼は英語を教えるまい。?

Comment: Do you think "He won't teach English." and "He won't teach English any more" are the same?

Comment: As noted below, my understanding of もう was lacking.

Comment: For the record, ジョン was absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case もう gives the meaning "any more". Without it, the sentence would mean:
"He probably doesn't teach English".

Note that 教えるまい has the same meaning as 教えないだろう. The latter form is more commonly used but the former is still used in writing sometimes.

Comment: Oh. I thought it just mean "even" or "still". Such as: He **still** hasn't found his keys.

Comment: @dotnetN00b The most common meanings for もう are "already" and "any more". He **still** hasn't found his keys would be  **まだ** 鍵（かぎ）を見つけていない. Is that what you're thinking of? As for "even", that sounds like yet another word, but without some context I couldn't say what the correct Japanese word would be.

Comment: I think I need to refer back to Genki 1. Maybe I'm remembering wrong...

Comment: @ジョン "Even" would probably be さえ or すら =)

Comment: @rintaun Yep, or even -ても :) In fact this is the most likely one if we're talking about Genki 1

Comment: @rintaun: I don't think so. I remember from the chapter when they introduce the -te iru form. I'm pretty sure that もう was in that chapter also.

Comment: @dotnetN00b What are you disputing exactly? さえ and すら are two candidates for "even", depending on context.

Comment: @ジョン - I was disputing rintaun's comment about -ても as opposed to もう in Genki 1. In either case, I'd have to verify when I get home.

Comment: @dotnetN00b I dont't see a comment like that from rintaun. Deleted?

Comment: @ジョン LOL. The comment was from you. Oops.

Comment: @dotnetN00b SE has suggested this discussion be [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3240/discussion-between--and-dotnetn00b). As for the comment, I was simply saying that -ても is a more likely candidate to be in Genki than さえ and すら. -ても and もう are completely different, so I'm not making any claims about one opposed to the other.