# "Let's not do this"

Tags: negation, imperatives, volitional-form

I wonder how to interpret the following sentence: "The weather is bad so let's not go out?". Basically, I want to stay as literal as possible and not end up saying "let's stay home" or using "if the weather's bad we better not go out".

Basically it would be something like:

> 天気が悪いので、出かけません＋しよう

If it cannot be literally translated, what are the other ways of expressing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could say something like this:

> 出かけ**ないでおこう**　　　　 (plain)
>   　 出かけ**ないでおきましょう** 　(polite)

Since your example includes 出かけません, I assume you want the polite version.

Answer (score 7):

You could also say it in the sense of "let's give up on going out".

> - 天気が悪いので、出かけるのを***やめよう***（かな）。

Answer (score 2):

I think your question may be answered with this post:

[Does -ou / -you / -mashou conjugation have a negative form?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/487/does-ou-you-mashou-conjugation-have-a-negative-form)

Probably the closest would be to:

- add まい to the dictionary form of the verb
- say stem-ないように

Comment: So, for instance: 出かけるまい？OR 出かけないように？The linked post suggests 出かけないだろう。

Comment: Yes, those would be correct. As for the post, I was referring to the later parts of the answer, not necessarily to the なかろう reference.