# How do I write "Let us not watch Titanic,"?

Tags: grammar

Hi I am currently doing a Japanese task **about inviting people** to a birthday party. I want to **write** that we will watch a movie but it will not be titanic. Is のはタイタニックを見ないようにしましょう right or did I get it wrong?

What would be a good way to write the details of the party on the invitation?

Comment: [perhaps this answer to another question might help](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/490/542)

Comment: What do you mean by 「のは」？

Comment: Maybe not what you had in mind, but I'd go with "タイタニック以外の映画を観ましょう。".

Comment: perhaps (depending on the exact context) タイタニックはちょっと。。。ほかの映画にしたらどうだろうなって. alternatively: 映画は見るけどタイタニックは見ない。could be spiced up with ~見るつもり/予定だ or じゃない instead of は見ない

Comment: タイタニックをみないでおきましょう。

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14551/1478

Answer (score 1):

In a real life situation, I'd just go with

> 内容：映画鑑賞（※タイタニックを除く）

to make it clear and simple.